# How can I prevent '(aphostrophe) to be converted in &apos; while storing in table

Tags: oracle, plsql, linq-to-xml

When I parse the xml having '(aphostophe) as some value, it is getting stored as ' in database.
Can you please help me out in this?

Comment: Could you explain what you are doing with context and snippet? What tool do you use to parse XML?

Answer (score 1):

It's technically incorrect to have an actual apostrophe in an XML attribute since you can use them to enclose attribute values, so it is being encoded for you as &apos;. This is technically correct XML:

```
<hello>
     <world punc='!' />
</hello>
```

So they must be encoded to prevent a parser from misunderstanding what the `'` means. So it *should* be encoded into &apos;.

Comment: Agree with the sentiment, but in chrome and firefox, all the ampersand_apos in the answer are being displayed as '. Looks better in IE8 (and that isn't something i say often).

Comment: @Gary: I fixed my post so that you can understand what I am trying to say, thanks.